# CMake: API for controlling verbosity

Tags: java, jar, cmake

I am using a simple `jar` command to create a jar file in a [custom commmand](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm.jar
  COMMAND ${Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE} ARGS cf ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm.jar gdcm/*.class
  COMMENT "javac *.java; jar cf -> gdcm.jar"
)
```

Thus when I type `make GDCMJavaJar`, I get a nice and clean output:

```
javac *.java; jar cf -> gdcm.jar
building gdcm.jar
```

However I'd like to control the verbosity of the jar command when I pass the `VERBOSE=1` make flag. In other word I'd like that `make GDCMJavaJar VERBOSE=1` execute instead:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm.jar
  COMMAND ${Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE} ARGS cvf ${GDCM_LIBRARY_DIR}/gdcm.jar gdcm/*.class
  COMMENT "javac *.java; jar cf -> gdcm.jar"
)
```

See how I added `v` to the `jar` command.

How I can execute two different custom command depending on the runtime `VERBOSE` value (different from the cache entry: [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html)) ?

---

Of course, I picked a random command using an explicit call to `jar` command, instead of using something like [`add_jar`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html), this is simply for the sake of a simple & complete example.